# Strange separator on empty jface window

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have just created an empty jface window. But for some reason there is separator at the top of the window:

[image]

With menu bar it looks pretty ok. But if there is no menu bar that separator is shown nevertheless!

[image]

How can it be eliminated?

**UPD**

```
class Application extends ApplicationWindow {
    /**
     * @param parentShell
     */
    public Application() {
        super(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createContents(final Composite parent) {
        prepareShell(getShell());
        return parent;
    }

    protected void prepareShell(final Shell shell) {
        shell.setSize(450, 300);
    }
}
```

and main class

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application app = new Application();
        app.setBlockOnOpen(true);
        app.open();

        Display.getCurrent().dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: @aphex, there is almost only boilerplate code. May there is something wrong with my jface framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend Window, not Application window. The Window class doesn't have menu and status. Also you wouldn't have separator on the top of the screen.

Another way to solve the problem is to override the showTopSeperator() from ApplicationWindow

```
protected boolean showTopSeperator() {
    return false;
}
```